# Jmeter - pause when response assertion triggers?

Tags: jmeter

I've got a Jmeter test up and running on an API I'm building.
The API returns this if it gets overloaded:

```
{"status":{"type":"failure","cause":"internal","http":500}}
```

What I'd like to do is have JMeter also PAUSE if it gets that result.

I already have set up a Response Assertion that captures these errors. It seems like this should be a simple thing to set up, but I'm not seeing it. I see that I can add an If Controller, but that only works with Javascript vars.

Do I need to add a Regular Expression Extractor, grab that 'failure' as 'type' variable, and then add that to the If Controller?
Seems a little over-complicated?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [BeanShell Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Timer) to handle this situation.

It

- allows scripting so you can program timer behavior how you need;
- has access to jmeter context - via ctx variable - so you can handle ResponseCode condition.

[Here](http://ideoplex.com/id/1374/beanshell-timer-in-jmeter) you can find good article with example how to use.
And [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/demos/BeanShellAssertion.bsh) - how to access beanshell variables and handle response code.

Your condition will be something like this one:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("500") == true) { 
    . . .
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: script used in BeanShell Timer **should return value is used as the number of milliseconds to wait.**

Another question is what the reason to do this.
If you have load/stress-test scenario then these results are something you should get during your tests and analyze then.
If you have kind of "functional" test-scenario so you have to handle this situation in more general way, adding any kind of properly configured [timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to each sampler - to avoid overload or simulate "real-life" scenario.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check this out.  The reason I'm wanting to do this is that I'm trying to simulate what my real-world API situation will be -- our application has a built-in 'waiting' period if it encounters a result that's not immediate.  So I want the load test to test something more like what our actual usage will be, rather than just brute-force hammering.

Comment: By the way, I tried to give you a +1, but evidently i don't have enough reputation points to do that.  Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem really. That's not only for reputation.